# php sendmail is not redirecting to the given url?

Tags: php, sendmail, redirect

My php sendmailscript is not working, it sends the mail but it is not redirecting to the given url.

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] <> "POST")
die("You can only reach this page by posting from the html form");
if ($_POST["captcha_input"] == $_SESSION["pass"])
{
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
$mailuser = "rohit007@gmail.com";
$url = "index.html"; 
$header = "Return-Path: ".$mailuser."\r\n"; 
$header .= "From: form with captcha <".$mailuser.">\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html;"; 

$mail_body = '
<b>Name</b> : '. $_POST[Name] .'<br><br>
<b>Email</b> : '. $_POST[Email] . '<br><br>
<b>Mobile</b> : '. $_POST[Mobile] . '<br><br>
<b>Unit Type</b> : '. $_POST[select] . '<br><br>
<b>Comments</b> : '. $_POST[Query] . '<br>'
;
mail ($mailuser, 'Enquiry', $mail_body, $header);
echo 'THANKS ';
} else {
echo "Sorry! you did not pass the Security Check.<br><br>";
echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
}
?>
```

Comment: you set the location of the url after you output the meta with the variable in it

Comment: actually i am new to php, can you help me?

Comment: switch these lines echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; and  $url = "index.html";  so your variable is set before you output it

Comment: You should use the `header("Location: $url")` function in PHP rather than the meta HTTP-EQUIV tag. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Please use redirect header of PHP.
For PHP Email Tutorials please check following links.

- [Click here](http://goo.gl/MYC7dd)
- [Click here](http://swiftmailer.org/)